# How to get whole object if I have a value of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like below,

let  x = [{a:1, b:2}, {c:3, d:4}, {e:5, f:6}, {g:7, h:8}]

Now my question is if I am having "4" with me then how can I get the value of "c:3".

Kindly help me as I am novice in the vanilla js.

Comment: Is `4` related to key `d`?

Comment: Is the table static? Is 3 always with 4 in the same object? Will there be other 4's in other objects? We need a lot more information. Also, what have you tried? :-)

Comment: Both of the comments above, and what are you trying to achieve? Why this data structure specifically? What's your use case.

Comment: @Mamun yes 4 is related to key d

Comment: @Islam that value "4" is unique always

Answer (score 0):

The following would find any object that has a direct property with value 4:

```js
const valueIs = (value) => (object) => 
  Object.values(object).some((v) => v === value);

let x = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 }, { e: 5, f: 6 }, { g: 7, h: 8 }];

console.log(x.filter(valueIs(4)));
```

Using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

If it's an object like {c:3,d:4} you want to track, then just keep its reference separate so you don't even have to look up the object at first place, since apparently you are defining x yourself.

```js
let myObject = {
  c: 3,
  d: 4
}

let x= [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}, myObject, {
  e: 5,
  f: 6
}, {
  g: 7,
  h: 8
}]

console.log(myObject)

myObject.c = 10

console.log(myObject)
console.log(x)
```

that way you don't have to traverse collection at all to track a specific value, you can even change myObject.c value.